# How to call a tuple of the enumerate function?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a for loop in order to edit the index of a data-frame. In general though, I can't seem to understand how the `enumerate` function really works.

Say for instance I have a simple list such that:

```
eg = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

for i,j in enumerate(eg):
    print(i,j)
```

This returns a simple and easily understandable output of:

```
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
4  E
```

Hence, `i` is the count in the list and `j` is the actual value. But say I wanted to run something a little more complicated like the below:

```
indx = []

for i,j in enumerate(eg):
    if i < 4:
        indx.append(str(j[i]) + str(j[i+1]))
    else:
        next

print(indx)
```

Essentially I would like to concatenate consecutive entries in a meaningful manner, such that the desired output for the code above (if I actually knew what I was doing) would be something like:

```
indx = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE']
```

Ideally though, the for-loop would be able to concatenate these letters with the distance increasing one at a time, that is:

```
indx = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'AC', 'BD', 'CE', 'AD', 'BE', 'AE']
```

Not sure if what I am asking is fairly simple and I am missing something obvious, or if it would just be easier for me to go through the effort of manually specifying the list like I have above.

Any help however is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: btw: `next` doesn't do what you think it does - it is a function. You are probably thinking of `continue`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is the combinations of the items in `eg`. You can use the `combinations` method of the `itertools` package as follow:

```
from itertools import combinations
eg = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
[''.join(m) for m in combinations(eg,2)]
```

output:

```
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'CD', 'CE', 'DE']
```

if the order is important, you need to do it manually. You can do it in a nested loop like this:

```
stack = []
step_max = len(eg)
for j in range(1,step_max):
    for i in range(len(eg)-j):
        stack.append(str(eg[i])+str(eg[i+j]))

print(stack)
```

output:

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'AC', 'BD', 'CE', 'AD', 'BE', 'AE']
```

Comment: Is there any way I can change this code such that the output returned is ordered as follows instead:

['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'AC', 'BD', 'CE', 'AD', 'BE', 'AE']

Comment: @vicefreak04 I updated my answer to give it in the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Here `j` used in for loop is element of the list so you should not index that like `j[i]`. Use `indx[i]` and `indx[i+1]` while you are concatenating inside for loop.